# Ec2 : console not opening

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image: When i go for connect to My EC2 console then i get this kind of error]

- I tried so many aws documentarian but not get output
- when i go for connect to my EC2 console then i get this error

Comment: You have to provide details of your instance, operating system, security groups, subnets. Sadly your question lacks any relevant info.

Comment: operating system : Linux

Comment: security group ::   sgr-09a995173751f2e29 22 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 launch-wizard-2

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are attempting to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance by using **EC2 Instance Connect**.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from the IP range of the EC2 Instance Connect service, or from the whole Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

Given the information you have provided, I would suggest checking that the instance was launched in a **Public Subnet**.

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

Comment: i already do this but not working

Comment: If all the above have been correctly configured, then it will work.